# Return a 404 in public async Task OnGet(string slug) in Razor Pages if slug does not exist in CMS

Tags: razor-pages

I have the following Page Model method:

```
public class CarModel : PageModel
    {
public Car Car { get; private set; }

public async Task OnGet(string slug)
        {



            var client = clientManager.GetClient();


            var carPages = await client.GetBySlugAsync();

            CarPages= carPages.Items[0];

// if carPages.Items is null, out of range, or if CarPages is null, then return a 404

        }
}
```

Razor Page:

```
@page "/{slug}"
@model CarModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Some title";
}

<div>Some markup</div>
```

If I enter a slug in the browser that does not exist in the CMS then I want the OnGet method to return a 404. How do I do that (best practice example)?

(currently, if I enter a non-existent slug in the browser, hit return, I will get a server error)

Haven't found any example on Microsoft docs for Razor Pages.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `NotFound` method that returns a `NotFoundResult`:

```
var carPages = await client.GetBySlugAsync();
if(!carPages.Any()) // or whatever the appropriate test is for your data type here
{
    return NotFound();
}
else
{ 
    return Page();
}
```

You will need to change the signature of the `OnGet` method to return an `IActionResult`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet(string slug)
```

See more about the range of `ActionResult` types available: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results